# How to display a list of items on the right with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I align a list of item in the right side as a list using flexbox?

something like this?

[image]

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>List</span>
  <span>3 oranges</span>
  <span>4 apples</span>
  <span>6 bananas</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate the two elements.

Something like this:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<div>      
<span>List</span>
</div>
<div>
  <div>3 oranges</div>
  <div>4 apples</div>
  <div>6 bananas</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `<div>` around the first `<span>` is not *strictly* necessary, but likely is desirable.

Comment: yes, you're right. It "looks" better :-)

Answer (score 3):

1. Group the last three `<span>` in a `<p>`
2. Wrap the first `<span>` and `<p>` in a `<div>`

Use semantic elements: `p` for paragraphs / text.

### 1 - `justify-content: space-between;`

Add space between the two children of the `<div>`. Hence, the first the `<span>` and the `<p>` are pushed to the sides.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>List</span>
  <p>
    <span>3 oranges</span>
    <span>4 apples</span>
    <span>6 bananas</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

*I would use the first approach.*

---

### 2 - `margin-left: auto;`

Pushes the `<p>` to the right.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>List</span>
  <p>
    <span>3 oranges</span>
    <span>4 apples</span>
    <span>6 bananas</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

### 3 `margin-right: auto;`

Pushes the `<p>` to the right.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div > span {
  margin-right: auto;
} 

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>List</span>
  <p>
    <span>3 oranges</span>
    <span>4 apples</span>
    <span>6 bananas</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

### 4 - `flex-grow: 1;`

The first `<span>` takes as much space as available. Hence, `<p>` is pushed to the right.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div > span {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>List</span>
  <p>
    <span>3 oranges</span>
    <span>4 apples</span>
    <span>6 bananas</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="list">
  <span>List</span>
  <div>
  <span>3 oranges</span>
  <span>4 apples</span>
  <span>6 bananas</span>
  </div>

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.list div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

You should wrap the list in a div
and then the list items in another div to achieve the layout you want.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```css
.cont {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.cont div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div>
    <span>List</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>3 oranges</span>
    <span>4 apples</span>
    <span>6 bananas</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your HTML structure you can do like below:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p span:nth-child(n + 3) {
  width:100%;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>List</span>
  <span>3 oranges</span>
  <span>4 apples</span>
  <span>6 bananas</span>
</p>
```